# unable to build libcamera and libcamera-apps

Tags: libcamera

A very similar question was asked 8 days ago, but my issue is different. I get meson.build:3:0: ERROR: Options "raspberrypi" are not in allowed choices..."

I get the impression there is lots of churn - much of it caused by meson - and I am wondering if I should wait until after the pi5 comes out.  The last time i worked though getting the camera integrated with other C code, it took a month and a bit and now that code is broken. Are things going to be better in just a week? An actual API perhaps like [joan's pigpio c interface](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html)? (he says hopefully).

Comment: *"An actual API"* -> Not sure what you mean by "actual" but it looks real enough to me: https://libcamera.org/api-html/annotated.html  I also notice they have a mailing list, IRC channel, and online bug reporting/tracking: https://libcamera.org/contributing.html ...You are probably wasting your time with this here.  But **why don't you just use the pre-compiled packages from the distro** (I presume you're using RpiOS, but I would guess it's in everything)?

Answer (score 0):

Goldilocks is right: libcamera.org does have an API and in the end was also right - I was able to use the precompiled packages. The problem was that I had switched to using the 64bit os (and forgot that I wasn't using it before) and the  classic cpp error message completely side-tracked me into thinking I needed to recompile libcamera-apps.

The structure of libcamera-apps could do with separating the command-line processing from the required set of calls to libcamera functions.  Indeed in java I construct a string that is the required command-line to set up libcamera so that I can get frames. It was just easier than figuring out how libcamera-apps initiates libcamera.  A function called init(..) In c/cpp) that takes the values as per the commandline would be great (with documentation). No doubt once one understands how libcamera is working, the code in libcamera-apps is obvious, but a application programmer friendly interface to libcamera would be useful.